# OpenCart - How to test what category a product is in?

Tags: php, opencart, cart

Is it possible to test which category a product is in from the View Cart template?

This file: catalog/view/theme/my_theme/template/checkout/cart.tfl

I guess modifications need to be made to the controller (catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php) but I can't work out how to test for the category on that page.

Thanks in advance for any help, it's much appreciated.
Laurence

Comment: I am sorry, but is it not even clear what do you want to achieve. Anyway, here in SO You [should ask these types of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) otherwise the questions will be marked as [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and closed...

Comment: There is a table "database_prefix".product_to_category where you'll find the category_id corresponding to your product_id.